# Dynamic VariableFromString in objective C

Tags: iphone

I want to dynamically create variable from string in objective C.

Like `NSClassFromString` thats way. In that I want to access variable.

Any idea about this?

Comment: May you explain the issue a little more?

Comment: Great question friend. You should have given your project name too, we could have completed it for you :P. Jokes apart dear, these type of questions are not going to get answers easily. Please ask to the point not generic questions to get better results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to dynamically access a property of an object, that's easy to do using [Key Value Coding](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Concepts/AccessorConventions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002174).

If your class is KVC-compliant (most Apple classes are), then use the `valueForKey:`, or `valueForKeyPath:` method to access a property as a string.

Consider this example.

```
// Shoe.h
@interface Shoe {
    NSString *brand;
    NSNumber *size;
}

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *brand;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *size;

@end

// Shoe.m
@implementation 

@synthesize brand, size;

@end
```

Let's create and initialize a Shoe object first.

```
Shoe *someShoe = [[Shoe alloc] init];
someShoe.brand = @"Adidas";
someShoe.size = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:9.5];
```

Considering this example `someShoe` object, its brand or size can be accessed via a string.

```
NSString *brandName = [someShoe valueForKey:@"brand"];
```

Comment: k thank for your help... But how can i access via id to that particular objects in another class through string..Any idea about this?

Comment: not sure what you mean. could you give an example or update your question with more details?